# Python - Can I insert rows into one database using a cursor (from select) from another database?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlite, pyodbc

I am trying to select data from our main database (postgres) and insert it into a temporary sqlite database for some comparision, analytics and reporting. Is there an easy way to do this in Python? I am trying to do something like this:

Get data from the main Postgres db:

```
import psycopg2
postgres_conn = psycopg2.connect(connection_string)
from_cursor = postgres_conn.cursor()
from_cursor.execute("SELECT email, firstname, lastname FROM schemaname.tablename")
```

Insert into SQLite table:

```
import sqlite3
sqlite_conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
to_cursor = sqlite_conn.cursor()
insert_query = "INSERT INTO sqlite_tablename (email, firstname, lastname) values %s"
to_cursor.some_insert_function(insert_query, from_cursor)
```

So the question is: is there a `some_insert_function` that would work for this scenario (either using pyodbc or using sqlite3)?

If yes, how to use it? Would the `insert_query` above work? or should it be modified?

Any other suggestions/approaches would also be appreciated in case a function like this doesn't exist in Python. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You should pass the result of your select query to `execute_many`.

```
insert_query = "INSERT INTO smallUsers values (?,?,?)"
to_cursor.executemany(insert_query, from_cursor.fetchall())
```

You should also use a parameterized query (? marks), as explained here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute

If you want to avoid loading the entire source database into memory, you can use the following code to process 100 rows at a time:

```
while True:
    current_data = from_cursor.fetchmany(100)
    if not current_data:
        break
    to_cursor.exectutemany(insert_query, current_data)
    sqlite_conn.commit()
sqlite_conn.commit()
```

Comment: I was looking for a way to not use `fetchall()`, since it could create a huge list in memory depending on size of the data

Comment: You can use fetchmany(100) instead. You can try the following:

`while True:
    current_data = from_cursor.fetchmany(100)
    if not current_data:
        break
    to_cursor.exectutemany(insert_query, current_data)`

Answer (score 1):

You can look at executemany from pyodbc or sqlite. If you can build a list of parameters from your select, you can pass the list to executemany.

Depending on the number of records you plan to insert, performance can be a problem as referenced in this open issue. https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/120

Comment: Newer information re: pyodbc's `fast_executemany` property [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Features-beyond-the-DB-API#fast_executemany)